# What is exactly the input to a second lstm layer?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, sequence-to-sequence, time

I am often confused about the lstm with more than one layer.

Imagine i have two lstm layer with 3 cells each layer.

What is exactly the input to the second lstm layer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to the second LSTM layer is the output at each time step of the first LSTM layer.

Comment: But what exactly is the output of a lstm layer ? is it $h$ for each timestep  ?

Comment: Yes, the output of the first LSTM layer is the hidden state at each time step.

Comment: ah and these "$ht$ are then like the $x$ in the second lstm layer ?

Comment: What are "these $h_t$" and "the x"? I understand that you are looking at a picture but you did not share it so I can't possibly know what you are talking about.

Comment: i can explain it more detailed. So if i have stacked lstm layers, then i know that the input to the second lstm layer are my output values okay so far so good. But if these outputs are the next input then what is the hidden state in the second lstm ? I mean every lstm layer has input values and a beginning hidden state? what would be the beggining hidden state of the second lstm layer for the first timestep ?

Comment: The initial hidden state is provided externally for each layer.

Comment: okay i think i got it, so this means that are outputs(hidden states) from the first lstm to the second layer will behave like input data in the first layer with the initial hidden state which is always given in the layers ?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: my last question is: Can a hidden state $h_t$ from a lstm cell be a vector instead of a single value ?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual thing actually.

Comment: okay thx, i asked because of this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCzL96nL7j0 , he did not mention a vector just used single values ?

Comment: It seems that they used single values to make the explanation as simple as possible. In the real world most of the times the hidden states are vectors.